# How to use parallel on multiple computer to have a list of tasks done only once?

Tags: ssh, gnu-parallel, pssh

I am trying to use `parallel` on multiple server using `ssh`, what actually I would like to do is something like:

```
    parallel -s computer_list.txt < command.txt
```

where in `server_list.txt` there is list of server and in `command.txt` looks like

```
    fist_job.sh
    second_job.sh
    ...
```

But I don't want that all the server do all the jobs in the list, I want that each `*.sh` is executed just one time on a random server, all of them can reach all files that they need to execute each command.

In other words what I am looking for is a kind of generalization of:

```
   parallel < command.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this:

servers.txt

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
serverA
serverB
raspi10
raspi11
raspi12
raspi13
supercomputerA
supercomputerB
```

jobs.txt

```
job1
job2
job3
job4
job5
job6
```

Then use this `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read in list of jobs into array
jobs=( $(<jobs.txt) )

# Get randomised list of servers
servers=( $( gshuf servers.txt) )

# Assign each job to a server and execute in parallel
for ((i==0;i<${#jobs[@]};i++)) ; do
   echo "ssh \"${servers[i]}\" \"${jobs[i]}\""
done | parallel
```

**Example**

That generates the following input for **GNU Parallel**:

```
ssh "raspi12" "job1"
ssh "serverA" "job2"
ssh "serverB" "job3"
ssh "raspi13" "job4"
ssh "server3" "job5"
ssh "supercomputerB" "job6"
```

---

**Notes**:

`gshuf` is how `GNU shuf` (shuffle) is installed on a Mac. It may be known as `shuf` on other machines.

Comment: I make the same implicit assumption as the question - that there are more servers than tasks. If not the case, just shuffle the `servers.txt` a few more times to make the servers array longer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
parallel --slf computer_list.txt < command.txt
```

I use version 20180822.